# Weights and Biases; cannot run code on my local PC

Tags: python, hyperparameters

I have some code that when I run on Colab it takes too long. So I decided to run the code on my machine. I am running an agent to optimise the hyperparameters. However the code execution seems to get stuck at the "with" statement, the next line does not get executed. My breakpoint indicates that the config is set to none.
Why does this work on Colab but not on my machine?

```
wandb.agent(sweep_id, function=trainer, count=6)

def trainer(config=None):
    print("Trainer")
    with wandb.init(config=config):
        print("After with")
        config = wandb.config
```